# Get the parent HTML element of certain type with JS

Tags: javascript, html

My code looks like this, in closeup:

```
<h2>
<span class="stuff">[<a id="someid">stuff</a>]</span> <span class="moreStuff">Another test</span>
</h2>
```

I've found a way to select my `a` element, and attach an id to it. What I need to do now is select its parent `<h2>` element, but not the `<span>` element. How can I do that (JQuery allowed)?

Edit: when I retrieve the selected `<a>`s, I get an array of them (there's lots of these structures on my page). When I try to write `myArray[someIndex].closest("h2")`, it says that the element does not have a `closest()` method. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One ways is to use the [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method of jQuery, with a selector. Something like this.

```
$("#someid").parents("h2");
```

**Update:**

You can use the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method with a selector, to only get the closest parent that match the selector.

```
$("#someid").closest("h2");
```

**Update 2:**

It would be a bit more work to do it with plain JavaScript. Not sure if it is the most efficient, but one way would be to select the element with `document.getElementById()` and then get a reference to its parent through the `parentNode` property. Then you would have to check if it is an `h2` element, and if not, look at that elements parent node, and so on.

You could check the jQuery source and see how they have implemented the closest method.

Comment: One more thing: how would I make sure it *only* selects the nearest h2, and not any other h2 that the `<a>` is in?

Comment: @Bluefire Do you have multiple `h2` elements nested in each other?

Comment: In theory, no, but anything can happen. Mind you, I won't just be using this for `<a>`s and `<h2>`s :D

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson what should the code be if we use pure js

Comment: Thanks, I got more information about what .closest() really do by viewing it with breakpoint on chrome developer tools

Answer (score 2):

I just needed the same thing. here a vanilla javascript variant:

```js
function findParent(startElement, tagName) {
  let currentElm = startElement;
  while (currentElm != document.body) {
    if (currentElm.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName.toLowerCase()) { return currentElm; }
    currentElm = currentElm.parentElement;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<h2>` is not the parent of the `<a>` but it is an ancestor, use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select it

```
$("#someid").closest("h2");
```

Answer (score 1):

try use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) for get exactly double or more level up the DOM tree.

```
$("#someid").parent().parent();
```