# "Pair up" sets of elements on HTML page with classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525379/get-the-parent-html-element-of-certain-type-with-js) question. I have lots of structures on my page that look a bit like this:

```
<h2>
<span class="stuff">[<a href="whatever">stuff</a>]</span> <span class="moreStuff">Another test</span>
</h2>
```

I would like to "pair up" the `<a>` and the `<h2>` in every one of these, e.g. give them the same class, so that when I select an `<a>` I can also select the "corresponding" `<h2>`. How would I go about doing that (as with the previous question, JQuery is more than welcome)?

Comment: what do you mean by "select"?

Comment: I mean, well, selecting an element. So `$("html")` would select the main `<html>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for the first time: I would just use something like this:

```
$("my selector").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("class", "pair" + i);
    $(this).closest("h2").attr("class", "pair" + i);
}
```

Comment: Instead of using attr("class", value) use addClass(value), doing so you don't take the risk of wyping any other class you had before on your objects.